# how to call ajax method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code

```
<li id="btemaildelete"><a href="##" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Email Address?');"><i class="cus-cancel"></i> Delete</a></li>
```

and wanted to call the following

```
emaildelete.cfm?intuserid=1
```

Can you please help me understand how?

Answer (score 1):

If you have jQuery included:

```
$.get("emaildelete.cfm", {intuserid: 1}, function(data) {
    // data contains the response of emaildelete.cfm
});
```

To catch the click event in jQuery you can do:

```
HTML:
<a href="..." data-id="1">Delete</a>

JavaScript:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[data-id]").click(function() {
       var confirm = confirm("Are you sure u wanna delete?");
       if(!confirm) return false;

       var deleteId = $(this).data("id");
       $.get("emaildelete.cfm", {intuserid: deleteId}, function(data) {
           // data contains the response of emaildelete.cfm
       });

       return false;
    });
});
```

With that code you don't need the "onclick" attribute anymore.

Comment: Coldfusion code:            <li class="btemailactive"><a href="emailmarkactive.cfm?intUserID=#intUserID#&intCreatedBy=#intCreatedBy#&intOPt=1&intUniqueID=#intUniqueID#" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to mark this Email Address Active?');"><i class="cus-link"></i> Mark Active</a></li>

Now how to call ajax to launch the emailmarkactive.cfm with the parameters.

Comment: Can you give an id to the link?

Answer (score 0):

here is an example

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    data: '{ }',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        // Do something interesting here.
    }
});
```

Comment: `PageName.aspx/GetDate` ?

Comment: Not much use as an answer to be honest.

Comment: $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'emaildelete.cfm',
    data: '{ intuserid : ????????}',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        // Do something interesting here.
    }
});

Comment: what have u tried yet...post some code here...otherwise no one will be able to help u

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<li id="btemaildelete"><a href="##" onClick="call_function();"><i class="cus-cancel"></i> Delete</a></li>
```

In your javascript code:

```
function call_function() {
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Email Address?'))
     {
     $.ajax({
     url: "emaildelete.cfm?intuserid=1",  //Or any other server page you want
     type: "POST",
     success: function (response) {
      alert('Success' + response);
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the id from the link itself, not sure how you're populating those links via aspx honestly. you just need to get the id for the email into the id for the link however your application can do that.

```
<li class="btemaildelete"><a href="##" class="deleteLink" id="get your ID in here" 
onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Email Address?');"><i 
class="cus-cancel"></i> Delete</a></li>

$(".deleteLink").on("click",function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'emaildelete.cfm',
    data: '{ intuserid : $(this).attr("id") }',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        alert('Email deleted');
    }
});
});
```